# Questions no longer being accepted from my account

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, user-accounts

I have in my account 54 reputation and 18 questions - 17 of them were answered and accepted.

4 of these questions were voted up, others didn't get votes up or down, and 2 question were voted down. These 2 questions are among the ones I got answers to and accepted them - There's nothing else to add or edit in them. Another question that I asked was deleted because of being opinion based. Therefore, even if I undelete and edit it, the question is still irrelevant to the forum because of being opinion based. Another question was deleted by me some time ago.

I'm not sure what else I can do in order to be unbanned? I've seen in the Help Center the suggestion "Begin by fixing your existing posts", but as I mentioned, the problems were already solved.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, one question.

Comment: One that you can remember, or one that you can see on [your profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2653179/user2653179?tab=questions&sort=newest) when you have enabled "show deleted posts" at the bottom? In any case, there is no magic get out of jail card here, and the actual contributing factors to the ban are not public. The only way you can remove the ban is by following the instructions in the duplicate.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, one question was deleted by the Community (Visible in "deleted recent questions") and one question was deleted by me (Not visible but I remember deleting it).

Comment: Who deleted it doesn't matter all that much, I suspect. What was the score of the one community deleted, and why? Link for us 10Kers? What was the score of the one you deleted, and why did you delete it?

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian, yes I'm sure. I don't have my account for long and also didn't ask many questions, so I remember it.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, the score was -4, closed as primarily opinion-based. I'm not sure how to link it, since the link takes me to a "Page Not Found" page. The question I deleted was few months ago. It's not visible to me as far as I can tell. Can't remember what was it or its score... I just remember deleting it.

Comment: @user2653179 You can right-click the link you tried to follow, copy the URL, and paste it here. I'm surprised you can't see it but 10K users should be able to. Not that this changes the outcome (you've been unbanned), but just for the curious...

Comment: @AaronBertrand, I can see it, but thought that others can't because of "Page not Found". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21665801/k-nearest-neighbors-in-c

Comment: I can see it, thanks. Yeah, I suggest you be very careful about asking a question like that one again.

Comment: Looking at your account, I think you should start to provide some good answers to quesions, before asking more.   A few upvoted answers does wonders for keaping the question ban away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you're not blocked *right now*, but be careful: you are right on that edge of potentially having your account blocked again. The *voting* on your content is a measurement of how much the community finds your content worthwhile, and most of your posts have been either down-voted or not voted on at all.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. It seems I got unbanned after asking this question here.

Comment: @user2653179 It was probably because you got a couple of sympathy up-votes after posting here. Please don't make this a habit. :-)